# Returning a variable out of a while condition

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I would like to return a variable out of this method.
YES I did make it static string. And tried to return a variable where the Messagebox.Show is. I even had that equal a variable and tried to return it. But I can't seem to return from inside the while brackets. And I can't get the variable outside the brackets to return. WHAT TO DO? The code works using a MessageBox, but I need the string variable.

```
static void rsnREAD(string dbTbl)
    {
        OleDbConnection machStopDB = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + @"C:\Users\sgarner\Google Drive\Visual Studio 2012\Write_to_db\Write_to_db\Machine_Stop.accdb");
        //string sDate;
        //sDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyy HH:mm:ss");
        string str = "SELECT LAST(REASON) AS lastREASON FROM "+dbTbl+"";
        OleDbCommand rdCmd = new OleDbCommand(str, machStopDB);
        try
        {
            machStopDB.Open();
            OleDbDataReader reader = rdCmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                MessageBox.Show(reader[0].ToString());
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            machStopDB.Close();
        }
        machStopDB.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Which value are you trying to retrieve? The first value in the reader? Last?

Comment: Why don't you show the code you have that is actually trying to return a variable.  This method has a `void` result, meaning it won't return anything and it doesn't match your description.

Comment: Other comments: Don't repeat yourself by having connection string in each function (if in fact you do have other functions like this). Don't show end users internal details of errors or mix UI concerns in a db call, i.e. `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);`

Comment: Also, you're potentially open to SQL Injection, although we can't see enough of your code to tell for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create the `String` variable outside the try block and set it when you read the value from database. Also change the return type of the method to `string` instead of `void`. You can use `if` instead of `while` because you are reading only one value from database.

```
static string rsnREAD(string dbTbl)
    {
      string result = string.Empty;
      using(var machStopDB = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + @"C:\Users\sgarner\Google Drive\Visual Studio 2012\Write_to_db\Write_to_db\Machine_Stop.accdb");
      {
        string str = "SELECT LAST(REASON) AS lastREASON FROM "+dbTbl+"";
        OleDbCommand rdCmd = new OleDbCommand(str, machStopDB);
        try
        {
          machStopDB.Open();
          using(var reader = rdCmd.ExecuteReader())
          {
            if(reader.Read())
            {
                result = reader[0].ToString();
            }
          }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) // Sample only. Catch only ones you need.
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
      }
      return result;
    }
```

Therefore, if the returned value is empty string either database is empty or there was an error.

Comment: We can also eliminate the redundant machStopDB.Close() at the end since this is covered by the finally block.

Comment: @BrianRogers Yes, didn't notice that. Changed

Comment: Why not just return from inside the if? Arguably not as good style, but there's some clarity in having separate returns for success and failure, too.

Comment: Regarding the code OP presented, in that case he wouldn't be able to close the Reader and the database connection which is essential for next queries.

Comment: Close should be in finally-block anyway, no?

Comment: Yes but to me, it is not logical if you first return and then expect finally to be executed. Yes it is possible and will work but that is something I would never do.

Comment: I've edited your code to remove `close` calls. Feel free to revert.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Cool, but IMH when accessing database try-catch-finally is the classic approach and therefore I like to always do that. I think `using` is lately overestimated. I tend to use it when an object should be disposed of or when working with streams but not when accessing database.

Comment: I think that the `using` statement is the normal way to do this. That's its entire purpose - to avoid having to write `finally` blocks.

Comment: Why would I don't want to write finally blocks? I think it is a matter of habit and/or how we did it the first place. In most programming languages (like Java, C++ and others), you would enclose with try-catch access to database and then close the connection. I don't see the specific purpose of the using statement here but to avoid calls to Close() method which is normal to call.

Comment: In addition, I just changed OP's code in order to solve his problem, and point out what should be changed in order to get the proper result.I didn't want to learn him how to use using statement. I didn't revert the code because I find that this edited approach is still fine.

Comment: You want to write `using` because it makes less likely to handle it incorrectly - `using` is single statement and don't have any part that you can miss, unlike `try`/`finally` pair where it is perfectly ok to forget `finally` part if using `try`/`catch`. It also makes code shorter and removes the need to verify if `finally` is present and includes necessary checks (like null). On not modifying OP sample - there is no reason to write bad code (i.e. keep SQL injection bugs as done in some samples) under your own name...

Comment: I totally agree with you on everything, I'm always trying to pinpoint bad code and bad solutions and suggest what could be wrong in the code or support others that pointed that out (buy upvoting answers and comments or commenting). Therefore I will say that maybe I'm a bad programmer and maybe its bad but its my habit, when it comes to databases, to use try-catch-finally blocks. Also, I support your edit just wanted to say that I personally wouldn't write it that way although I think it's fine. No heart feelings.